# jQuery animate runs correctly only once, then starts behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have the following JavaScript/jQuery code. I can't see any problem with it but it's not working correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $("#forumHeader").animate({top: '250px'});
        }
        else
        {
            $("#forumHeader").animate({top: '60px'});
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#forumHeader
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

#content
{
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="forumHeader">Forum Header</div>
<div id="content">Some content here</div>
```

The first time I scroll down it is working as it should and animating #forumHeader top: 250px. But when I scroll back up again, it may take multiple seconds before it animates back to top: 60px. Sometimes it is changing back and forth, sometimes it may not do anything. What is the problem? Please help ..

Comment: The scroll event runs far more times than once while you are scrolling. Adding/removing a class and animating with css would likely have better results rather than queuing up thousands of animations.

Comment: Any solution in regards to handling the scroll event should use some form of a throttle/debounce so that the scroll event is not processed repeatedly for one (from the user's perspective) scroll action.  It's also advised to move selectors outside of the scroll event handler, such as `$("#forumHeader")`, and cached so a variable reference to the element can be used rather than performed every time, to increase performance.

Comment: @Taplar that didn't even cross my mind, thanks. I have updated the code below.

Comment: Quick example using a debounce.  https://jsfiddle.net/6bp0mzap/

Comment: @Taplar that's awesome! thanks for enlightening me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use use the jQuery to add and remove a class, then use a CSS transition

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     // EDIT - Move the selector outside of the scroll event as suggested
     var header = $("#forumHeader");

     $(window).scroll(function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            header.addClass('slide');
        } else {
            header.removeClass('slide');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#forumHeader{
    top: 60px;
    -webkit-transition: top 500ms ease-out ;
    -moz-transition: top 500ms ease-out ;
    -o-transition: top 500ms ease-out ;
    transition: top 500ms ease-out ;
}
#forumHeader.slide{
    top: 250px;
}
#content
{
height: 1000px;
background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="forumHeader">Forum Header</div>
<div id="content">Some content here</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I get that this fires the function a lot, but I've used similar solutions on sites and not noticed any performance issues. If you have any other suggestion on how to improve this type of scroll function that would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: That seems to work as I want it to and I also realise that it's an more effective method. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: @Jim-miraidev quick example thrown together using a form of a debounce.  https://jsfiddle.net/6bp0mzap/